Integral involving the distance of a closed set of finite measure
Let $F \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a closed set with $m(F^c)<\infty$. Set
$$I(x)= \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{d(y,F)}{|x-y|^{n+1}}dy$$
where $d(y,F)= \inf_{x\in F} |y-x|$ is the Euclidean distance from $y$ to $F$. Show that $I(x)<\infty$ for almost all $x\in F$.
Here is my attempt:
Suppose that $x\in F$, then we have that
$$I(x)= \int_{F} \frac{d(y,F)}{|x-y|^{n+1}} dy +\int_{F^c} \frac{d(y,F)}{|x-y|^{n+1}}dy = \int_{F^c} \frac{d(y,F)}{|x-y|^{n+1}} dy$$
It suffices to show that $\int_F I(x) dx <\infty$. For this, we have by Fubini's Theorem:
\begin{align*}
    \int_F \int_{F^c} \frac{d(y,F)}{|x-y|^{n+1}} dy dx &= \int_{F^c} \int_F \frac{d(y,F)}{|x-y|^{n+1}} dx dy \\
    &\leq \int_{F^c} \int_F \frac{1}{|x-y|^n } dx dy 
\end{align*}
where the second inequality comes from the fact that for $x\in F$, $d(y,F) \leq |x-y|$.
Here, I want to bound the inner integral by $m(F)$ or some other constant, but I am not sure how to deal with the remaining factor of $|x-y|$. Any suggestions?
